# What is causing ld: duplicate symbol

Tags: c++, include, header-files, ld

ld: duplicate symbol StringFunctions::intToString(int) in

```
/Build/Intermediates/Y36PJC-mrvikmil.build/Debug/Y36PJC-mrvikmil.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ServerSocket.o and 
/Build/Intermediates/Y36PJC-mrvikmil.build/Debug/Y36PJC-mrvikmil.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
```

for architecture x86_64

function *StringFunctions::intToString(int)* is in **StringFunctions.h**

includes from **main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Exception.h" //does not include anything more
#include "ServerConsole.h"
    /* 
       which includes ServerSocket.h which includes ClientSocket.h which includes StringFunctions.h
       AND
       ServerSocket.h includes SocketException.h which includes StringFunctions.h
    */
```

includes from **ServerSocket.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "InvalidPortException.h" //does not include anything more
#include "SocketException.h" //which includes StringFunctions.h
#include "ClientSocket.h"    //which includes SocketException.h which includes StringFunctions.h
#include "StringFunctions.h" //StringFunctions.h

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

I believe that as long as i have things in .h files, i can include pretty much anything anywhere...

All my files has include guard (#ifndef ... #define ...)

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define the function as `inline` or move its implementation to a cpp file. Otherwise it will exist in both objects and C++ won't know which one (despite them being identical) to link.

Include guards will avoid having the same header multiple times in the same code file/object. However they won't avoid having the same piece of code in multiple object files, as each one is create on its own with all defines reset.

Comment: I think you mean multiple translation units will define the same method. +1

Comment: Thanks, that help me and save my remaining half day for searching on google...thanks again.